# Classic 350 Heavy engine noise

Tags: motorcycle, noise, enfield-classic, royal-enfield

After the first service of new classic 350, I began to hear a heavy sound from engine, which is not consistent. But when it came, it is breaking my heart :( .

After the service I contacted the service center due to this noise. But at the time when I brought my bullet to service center, there were no noise. So then they told me like it was the sound of tappet and all new bullets have the same issue and it will be gone after completing 9000kms.

After a few kilometers the noise disappears. After riding nearly 2300kms, yesterday the noise again showed up. But this time the noise was really really heavy. When I ride the bullet, every body will stare at me and started asking me what happened to your new bullet.

Today morning I brought the bullet to the service center and this time they told me that the noise is because there may be some dirt or something  else in the engine oil. They scheduled a service for fixing it with the second service within two days.

I am scared these kind of issues may affect the engine or not.

Please help to figure out what to do?

Comment: What you are looking for is for us to tell you that there's no problem. We can't do that.

Comment: Do you have a recording or video with the sound? Really hard to tell from just a description

Comment: This is a new bike. You should not have problems with it. Take it back to the dealer you purchased it from and insist they fix it or replace it.

Answer (score 1):

Using second service within 2 days will affect your insurance premium, seems defect left in Quality check.

It should be fixed without any charge or atleast not using free service(free service price is including in MRP & is paid to service center by company). Many recent owners(my many friends) reported issues with faulty light console, faulty filters & very few but definite issue in clutch box. Service center tend to try to cash that without understanding the issue or considering it as manufacturing defect.

Escalate to next level of management. Good Luck